# Yahoo Weather API for United Kingdom

Tags: ios, yahoo, weather

I am trying to make a application for iPhone which tells weather for different locations of United Kingdom but I could not found API for that so can anybody please help me to find Yahoo API?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get the WOEID for a location.  You can use Yahoo's Placefinder API:

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/

Then you can use the Yahoo Weather API:

http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/